# How to pass parameters to login action?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to have a different bunch of statements get executed in the login action based on the parameter passed through url. In appController I've a code like this:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if(isset($this->passedArgs['type']) && ($this->passedArgs['type'] == 1)) {
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'type' => 1);
    } elseif(isset($this->passedArgs['type']) && ($this->passedArgs['type'] == 2)) {
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'type' => 2);
    } else {
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'type' => 1);
    }
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'index');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
}
```

But, when I pass parameters I'm unable to login as the var_dump($this->data) is empty array. When I remove the parameters it works just fine. Please someone let me know whether this is the right way to pass parameters to the action?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle that inside of your login() action.

For an example of a login action see this https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/2.0/Controller/UsersController.php#L336

If the user logged in successfully check the passed args for whatever you're looking for and redirect based on that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My problem is when I pass the argument through URL, $this->data is getting empty and I'm unable to login.